# date and time input format not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

forms.py

```
class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model = Report
      manual_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput())
      widgets = {'manual_date': forms.DateInput(attrs{'size':'15','id':'datepicker1',}),'manual_time':
          forms.TimeInput(attrs={'size':'8','class':'time_field', },format='%H:%M')
     }
```

Form accepting the input only in this format selected `(mm/dd/yyyy and 24hrs)`.If the selected format is in `(dd/mm/yyyy and 12hrs)` ,i am not able to save the changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally this worked for me

```
class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    manual_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y','%d/%m/%Y'],
                      widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'size':'15','id':'datepicker'},format=["%m/%d/%Y","%d/%m/%Y"]))
    manual_time = forms.TimeField(input_formats=['%H:%M','%I:%M %p'],
                      widget=forms.TimeInput(attrs={'size':'8','class':'time_field'},format=["%H:%M","%I:%M %p"]))
```

Problem is with Input_formats,so making changes in both date and time input_formats given the solution.

Hope this helps someone!Thanks